# "With that name" or "by that name"?

Tags: prepositions

Could you tell me which preposition, *with* or *by* do I need to use before *that name* in the dialogue below?

> Person A: Does Sara Smith live in that house?
>
> Person B: Sorry, I don't know anyone **with**/**by** that name?

I would've thought that *with* is the right choice there, but I've heard people use *by*. Are both perfectly natural?

Comment: with here=buzzer

Comment: In Britain we often say 'I don't know anyone (or a shop, company, place, street, town, etc) **by** that name'. Or 'with', meaning the same thing.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Do you think that **with that name** you can parade around this town? :)

Comment: There's a third alternative: *I don't know anyone **of** that name*

Comment: In the U.S., "I don't know anyone by that name" is far more common than "with that name."

Comment: I don't know if this is the reason *why*, but we say "He goes **by** the name 'Fred Bloggs'", not "He goes *with* the name..."

Comment: @stangdon - we could also use 'goes by' like this - he is called Lawrence James Peter Doggett but he **goes by** the name of 'Larry the Dog'.